# FuckItJS equivalent for Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, rubinius

> FuckItJS
>
> Javascript Error Steamroller
>
> FuckItJS uses state-of-the-art technology to make sure your javascript
>   code runs whether your compiler likes it or not.
>
> Technology
>
> Through a process known as Eval-Rinse-Reload-And-Repeat, FuckItJS
>   repeatedly compiles your code, detecting errors and slicing those
>   lines out of the script. To survive such a violent process, FuckItJS
>   reloads itself after each iteration, allowing the onerror handler to
>   catch every single error in your terribly written code.

I'm determining what code in `lib/my_file.rb` is causing Rubinius to have the following error:

```
$ ruby lib/my_file.rb 
An exception occurred running lib/my_file.rb
    Error trying to compile /path/to/lib/my_file.rb (Rubinius::CompileError)

Backtrace:
 Rubinius::Compiler.compiler_error at /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/rbx-1.2.4
                                      /lib/compiler/compiler.rbc:11
        Rubinius::Compiler.compile at /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/rbx-1.2.4
                                      /lib/compiler/compiler.rbc:62
  Rubinius::CodeLoader#compile_file at kernel/delta/codeloader.rb:146
     Rubinius::CodeLoader#load_file at kernel/delta/codeloader.rb:118
   Rubinius::CodeLoader#load_script at kernel/delta/codeloader.rb:61
   Rubinius::CodeLoader.load_script at kernel/delta/codeloader.rb:90
            Rubinius::Loader#script at kernel/loader.rb:618
              Rubinius::Loader#main at kernel/loader.rb:762

Caused by: undefined method `body' on an instance of Rubinius::AST::SplatValue. (NoMethodError)

Backtrace:
  Kernel(Rubinius::AST::SplatValue)#body (method_missing) at kernel/delta/kernel.rb:79
  Rubinius::AST::OpAssign1#initialize at /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/rbx-1.2.4
                                         /lib/compiler/ast/operators.rbc:136
 Rubinius::Melbourne#process_op_asgn1 at /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/rbx-1.2.4
                                         /lib/melbourne/processor.rbc:332
      Rubinius::Melbourne#file_to_ast at /private/var/folders/3x
                                         /y_8y8vr53ws_kxj97km79q5h0000gn/T
                                         /ruby-build.20120706090940.39603
                                         /rubinius-1.2.4/lib/ext/melbourne
                                         /melbourne.cpp
       Rubinius::Melbourne#parse_file at /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/rbx-1.2.4
                                         /lib/melbourne.rbc:83
 Rubinius::Compiler::FileParser#parse at /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/rbx-1.2.4
                                         /lib/compiler/stages.rbc:219
  Rubinius::Compiler::Parser(Rubinius::Compiler::FileParser)#run at \
          /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/rbx-1.2.4/lib/compiler/stages.rbc:202
               Rubinius::Compiler#run at /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/rbx-1.2.4
                                         /lib/compiler/compiler.rbc:332
           Rubinius::Compiler.compile at /Users/agrimm/.rbenv/versions/rbx-1.2.4
                                         /lib/compiler/compiler.rbc:58
     Rubinius::CodeLoader#compile_file at kernel/delta/codeloader.rb:146
        Rubinius::CodeLoader#load_file at kernel/delta/codeloader.rb:118
      Rubinius::CodeLoader#load_script at kernel/delta/codeloader.rb:61
      Rubinius::CodeLoader.load_script at kernel/delta/codeloader.rb:90
               Rubinius::Loader#script at kernel/loader.rb:618
                 Rubinius::Loader#main at kernel/loader.rb:762
```

and currently I'm commenting in and out parts of my code to see what causes the error. Is there a library that can automate this process?

Comment: The history of computing is strewn with systems that attempted to repair or remove errors from your code in order to keep going, either to find the next syntax error or to attempt to keep going.  There hasn't been one that hasn't caused a million cascading syntax errors.

Comment: @PaulTomblin My aim isn't to remove the error-causing code, but to determine what code causes Rubinius to throw an exception, and report that as a bug to the Rubinius project.

Comment: `Kernel(Rubinius::AST::SplatValue)#body (method_missing) at kernel/delta/kernel.rb:79`
The backtrace says it's something on that line calling an undefined method

Comment: @ashgromnies That doesn't fully determine what code in `lib/my_file.rb` caused the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fuckit.rb

https://github.com/programble/fuckit.rb